# Why take macroscopic average of electric field over length scale smaller then the Debye length?

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, debye-length

In Landau and Lifshitz volume 10 pg117 the authors say that  the electric and magnetic fields $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are averaged over regions "having dimensions large compared with the distances between the particles but small compared with the Debye length".

I have seen other authors say that the average is taken over length scales much larger then the Debye length.

Why would we want it small compared with the Debye length because surely this gives effects due to the fact that the fields have not being effectivly screened?

Comment: I think you are asking about the conversion from a truly microscopic to a macroscopic form of Maxwell's equations, are you not?  If so, the proper method is to perform a spatial ensemble average.  The size of the spatial scales over which you average are dependent upon the problem you wish to solve.  The necessity of a large scale relative to inter-particle separation arises from the need to have sufficient particles to make the ensemble average statistically significant (e.g., makes no sense if only one particle exists in the volume of interest).